# jhipster application-prod.yml stores sensitive info on github

Tags: github, jhipster

I want to keep my smtp login information private. And its a hassle to edit application-prod.yml every time I have to deploy to production.

What is the correct method to avoid storing sensitive details in application-prod.yml on github ?

Answer (score 3):

Many different ways depending on where and how you deploy to:

- Don't store application-prod.yml in git and don't package it in your jar
- Don't store secrets in application-prod.yml, use environment variables or command line options. See [Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).
- Encrypt secrets using [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) in application-prod.yml
- Store secrets in external Spring Cloud Config Server (e.g. [JHipster Registry](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry)) or [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io)

and many other ways...