# Dealing with YAML config files and credentials

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, jhipster

With a Spring Boot application, the artifact of choice for deployment seems to be a single executable file, JAR or WAR. In one case, I have added my own encryption/decryption to the project so that I can check in my application configuration without plain-text credentials. If I build a deployment archive with a configuration file, that's checked in with empty credentials, I have to populate the credentials just before I package and deploy. Or, if I choose to use plain-text creds in the configuration file, I'm always forgetting to remove the creds and keep checking in the file with visible credentials.

I'm writing my question here to see if anyone has any bright ideas around how we can manage this, develop, checkin, package, and deploy without all this dancing around the YAML configuration files.

For a JHipster app my encryption/decryption solution at least protected the files from plain-text, but any sharp Java developer could use my encryption utility to decode the creds I check in.

What's the best strategy here? Could we easily add the creds with some scripts or Maven/Gradle operation? I'm game to change anything.

Comment: You should probably check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). If you don't want to commit your credentials, then don't and externalize your configuration. For example, you can create a separate `application.properties` and put it in the same folder as your .JAR/.WAR. Or you can use environment variables (eg. `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME`). But if you ask what the **best** strategy is, well, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow since it would lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for somewhere I could get opinionated answers if not here?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650601/jhipster-application-prod-yml-stores-sensitive-info-on-github/45652681#45652681 ?

Comment: @DavidWhitehurst no idea. I only know that Stack Overflow isn't the place to go. Related: [“Primarily Opinion Based” on “Best Practice” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337031/primarily-opinion-based-on-best-practice-questions). So, it's fine to ask for possible solutions to your question, and you can choose by yourself what the best solution could be, or you can wait and see how the community votes on the answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the obvious solution is to externalize the config both local and deployed. And, if I can override the template config (without the creds) in my git repo, I'll still have the template version of my configs local and in the repo.